# redefine buttons functionality by other buttons in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im trying to achieve construction in xamarin that will allow me to redefine bunch of buttons by two main buttons above them. The problem is that both sections of subbutton function become active after I click on the second main button. So when I click on button1 and then currency1button or currency2button the code works as intended but after i click on button2 and try to click on currency1button both `textView.Text=(""+currencyTable[startingCurrency].name)`and `textView1.Text=(""+currencyTable[endCurrency].name)` will execute. Thanks for any help you can provide and sorry for my bad english.

```
    button1.Click += delegate { 


            currency1button.Click += delegate {
                startingCurrency=1;
                textView.Text=(""+currencyTable[startingCurrency].name);


            };


            currency2button.Click += delegate {
                startingCurrency=2;
                textView.Text=(""+currencyTable[startingCurrency].name);

            };

};


button2.Click += delegate {



            currency1button.Click += delegate {
                endCurrency=1;
                textView1.Text=(""+currencyTable[endCurrency].name);

            };


            currency2button.Click += delegate {
                endCurrency=2;
                textView1.Text=(""+currencyTable[endCurrency].name);

            };


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're never removing the delegates from the button Click events.  Notice how when you add the delegate you use a "+=" operator.  In this context, that operator attaches another delegate to the event.  Events also have support the "-=" operator to remove a delegate.  But, in order to remove a delegate, you need to keep a reference to it.

Normally, I use methods here because it's easier to register and unregister a method than to keep references to anonymous delegates floating around.  Let's see both in action...

I am going to simplify my code a little bit and assume that there is only 1 currency button.

Using Captured Anonymous Delegates...

```
        Action currency1buttonCase1Delegate = delegate {
            // your handler code in here
        };

        Action currency1buttonCase2Delegate = delegate {
            // your handler code in here
        };

        button1.Click += delegate {
            // Remove click handlers
            currency1button.Click -= currency1buttonCase1Delegate;
            currency1button.Click -= currency1buttonCase2Delegate;
            // Add the delegate that you want for this event
            currency1button.Click += currency1buttonCase1Delegate;
        }

        button2.Click += delegate {
            currency1button.Click -= currency1buttonCase1Delegate;
            currency1button.Click -= currency1buttonCase2Delegate;

            currency1button.Click += currency1buttonCase2Delegate;
        }
```

Using Methods as Event handlers...

```
       button1.Click += delegate {
            // Clear all handles
            current1button.Click -= Currency1ButtonCase1;
            current1button.Click -= Currency1ButtonCase2;

            // Add the one we want
            currency1button.Click += Currency1ButtonCase1;
        };

        button2.Click += delegate {
            // Clear all handles
            current1button.Click -= Currency1ButtonCase1;
            current1button.Click -= Currency1ButtonCase2;

            // Add the one we want
            currency1button.Click += Currency1ButtonCase2;
        };
```

And at some point in the class you'll have to define the methods Currency1ButtonCase1 and Currency1ButtonCase2 with the code that was in your anonymous delegates.